Get values of columns A of table 1 and values of column B of table 2 with same ID
I have 2 tables 1 and 2, I will like to query to combine the result as below
Table_1



Row #
ID
Age
Color




1
1234
15
Red


2
1234
15
Yellow


3
1235
16
Green


4
1235
16
Yellow


5
1235
16
White


6
1235
16
Green


7
1236
21
Black


8
1236
21
Pink



Table_2



Row #
ID
Age
Fruit




1
1234
15
Orange


2
1234
15
Apple


3
1235
16
Banana


4
1235
16
Peach


5
1236
21
Banana


6
1236
21
Orange


7
1236
21
Kiwifruit



Query result should be



Row #
ID
Age
Color
Fruit




1
1234
15
Red
Orange


2
1234
15
Yellow
Apple


3
1235
16
Green
Banana


4
1235
16
Yellow
Peach


5
1235
16
White
Null


6
1235
16
Green
Null


7
1236
21
Black
Banana


8
1236
21
Pink
Orange


9
1236
21
Null
Kiwifruit



This looks like very easy, but I could not get it. I am using SQL Server 2019 database and SSMS19. I tried,
select t1.*, t2.Fruit
from Table_1 t1
left join Table_2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID


You're missing one join condition left join Table_2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.Row# = t2.Row#

As @DaleK has said, or you missing a join on Age left join Table_2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.Age = t2.Age

Hi Alan, here is the result:  Red ,Orange;
Red, Apple;
Yellow, Orange;
Yellow, Apple, But I do not want the Red and Yellow repeat. If number of fruit and color are not equal, I need to put a null value.

Based on your data set you need to generate your own rank within each ID/Age group to allow you to join between the tables. You then need to use FULL JOIN because you want data from either table. The following query gives your desired output:
DECLARE @T1 TABLE(RowID INT, ID INT, Age INT, Color VARCHAR(20));
INSERT  @T1(RowID, ID, Age, Color)
VALUES
    (1, 1234, 15, 'Red'),
    (2, 1234, 15, 'Yellow'),
    (3, 1235, 16, 'Green'),
    (4, 1235, 16, 'Yellow'),
    (5, 1235, 16, 'White'),
    (6, 1235, 16, 'Green'),
    (7, 1236, 21, 'Black'),
    (8, 1236, 21, 'Pink');

DECLARE @T2 TABLE(RowID INT, ID INT, Age INT, Fruit VARCHAR(20));
INSERT  @T2(RowID, ID, Age, Fruit)
VALUES
    (1, 1234, 15, 'Orange'),
    (2, 1234, 15, 'Apple'),
    (3, 1235, 16, 'Banana'),
    (4, 1235, 16, 'Peach'),
    (5, 1236, 21, 'Banana'),
    (6, 1236, 21, 'Orange'),
    (7, 1236, 21, 'Kiwifruit');

SELECT  RowID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ISNULL(t1.ID,t2.ID)),
        ID = ISNULL(t1.ID,t2.ID),
        Age = ISNULL(t1.Age,t2.Age),
        t1.Color,
        t2.Fruit
FROM    (   SELECT  *, RowNumber=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID,t.Age ORDER BY t.RowID)
            FROM    @T1 AS t
        ) AS t1
        FULL JOIN 
        (   SELECT  *, RowNumber=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID,t.Age ORDER BY t.RowID)
            FROM    @T2 AS t
        ) AS t2
            ON t2.ID = t1.ID
            AND t2.Age = t1.Age
            AND t2.RowNumber = t1.RowNumber


You should use right join to get null result if the relation is missing. But you should add one more table Table_1_Table_2 to make relation "one to one" or add column in table_1 table_2_ROW to manage this kind of structure. And the query
select t1.*, t2.Fruit
from Table_2 t2
right join Table_1_Table_2 t1_t2 on t1_t2.fruitRef_ROW = t2.ROW
right join Table_1 t1 on t1_t2.colorRef_ROW = t1.ROW`


The Query below should give you the correct result:
SELECT 
    COALESCE(t1.ID, t2.ID) AS ID,
    COALESCE(t1.Age, t2.Age) AS Age,
    t1.Color,
    t2.Fruit
FROM Table_1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_2 t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.Age = t2.Age
ORDER BY ID, Age, Color, Fruit;

